# Which logging tool/approach would you recommend?

Tags: logging, error-logging

I'm going to add Logging (to rolling text file + windows event source) for my application today so that later application debugging can be made possible and easier.

I've previously used Log4Net and Enterprise Library Logging Application Block and now thinking what tool to use. I've seen [this comparison of existing tools][1].

but ideally, I'd like to use native .NET classes such as classes in System.Diagnostics so that it can be used on any project, any client with highest performance. any sample application?

Which logging tool/approach have you worked with and would you recommend?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would like to recommend log4Net

Answer (score 0):

I would use log4net with the FileAppender:

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

You can make sure that the logging is as fast as possible by doing checks before each log call i.e. as follows to stop the calls being made if you do not have the respective level configured:

```
if (Log.IsInfoEnabled) Log.Info("Message");
```

This is as fast as you will get.

Make sure you define a logger inside your class as a static member i.e. then you have a one-time instantiation cost for all instances:

```
class X {
    readonly static ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(X));
}
```

Enterprise library logging has some serious performance problems so I'd avoid it like the plague.